# how do I make this post machine accept aab or baa?

Tags: computer-science, automata, turing-machines

so far I made it accept, a, aaa,bab but now I want strings aab or baa. How would I do this ?

this is what I have so far...

[image]

edit:
@Hagen von Eitzen
here is the example of Post Machine that a lot of books are using
for example you could do a string `aaabbb`

[image]

Comment: What does "Add a" mean here? AFAIK, a post machine can only write 0 and 1 as "actions", and all wrinting seems to be redundant if the task is only to recocnize a finite language ...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen well I am reading couple of books and they use for example ---> 'ADD a' ---> 'ADD b' ---> 'ADD b' ---> for a string abb

Comment: Can you somehow make a connection of this to the model e.g. described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%E2%80%93Turing_machine#1936:_Post_model)?